# Soap header changed after XSL transform

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xslt-1.0

I've been trying to generate XML using XSL file. But somehow the SOAP header tag is overridden by a different one.

My XSL file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="utf-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <!-- SOME DATA -->
            </SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <soap:Body>
            <!-- SOME DATA -->
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output XML is generated as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
<!--SOME DATA-->
  </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
<!--SOME DATA-->
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Whereas I expect it to look like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<!--SOME DATA-->
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <soap:Body>
<!--SOME DATA-->
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone please help me resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your soap en SOAP-ENV namespaces are the same, so the only thing that has changed is the that the second prefix has been dropped. In essence your message is the same, the prefix is just a placeholder for the namespace and you do not need two prefixes for the same namespace.

Basically the second prefix is unnecessary and is removed by the transformer.

Comment: That worked. I chaged the namespace to xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope". Thanks a ton for this quick help.